# Tomcat url redirection (not root)

Tags: tomcat, war, redirect

Is it possible to redirect specific url

http://10.99.77.170:8080/web/userview/MainView/_/inboxing

to

http://10.99.77.170:8080/web/userview/MainView/_/my_docs

It should not redirect url's like

http://10.99.77.170:8080/web/userview/MainView/_/inboxing?something=sth

As I am using one framework which doesnt allow me to do this, is it possible to make such and redirect using Apache Tomcat on which it is running ? 
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. What framework are you using? Do you want to write your own code? Do you want to use a pre-existing tool that can do this?

Comment: Hello thank you for asking, I am using Joget enterprise. I tried https://www.zlatkovic.com/httpredirectfilter.en.html , but it doesnt really work as I would need plus it is driving my server crazy (300+ % CPU usage [4core]). Do you have any tips how could i accomplished that redirect ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do conditional redirection is using [tuckey's url-redirect](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) project. It's packaged as a JAR file that you drop into your web app's `WEB-INF/lib/` directory and configure using `WEB-INF/lib/web.xml` and an external configuration file (to map incoming to outgoing URLs).

Their web site has extensive documentation about how to set up those mappings. You should be able to come up with a rule that does what you want it to do. Something like this:

```
<urlrewrite>
  <rule match-type="wildcard">
    <!-- The 'condition' is what prevents redirection when there is a query string-->
    <condition type="query-string" operator="notequal"></condition>
    <from>/userview/MainView/_/inboxing</from>
    <to type="redirect">/userview/MainView/_/my_docs</to>
  </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```